# unexpected keyword_end with every loop

Tags: ruby

I am getting an `unexpected keyword_end` error and I don't know why:

```
def add(meeting)
    if conflict?(meeting)
        puts "There's conflict with another meeting!"
    else
        if @meetings.empty?
            @meetings.push(meeting)
        else
            i = 0
            @meetings.each do |m|
                if m > meeting
                    @meetings.insert(i, meeting)
                    break
                end
                i++
            end
        end
    end
end
```

If I delete the `each` loop there is no problem. I have tried with a `while` loop and with an `until` loop and I am getting the same error in all of them.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you want the index you're on, you should use `each_with_index`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no unary operator `++` in Ruby. You should have:

```
i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In line 14, you are adding two numbers, but you forgot to pass the second number, instead the parser is encountering an `end`. So, the error message is slightly misleading: it's not that the parser isn't expecting an `end` there, rather it is expecting to see something *before* the `end`.